# Why can't a Composed Task execute other Composed Tasks in Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

After I create 2 Composed Tasks named `foo` and `bar`, I want to create another Composed Task named `baz` to run `foo && bar`. However, I failed to do so because of this error:

```
dataflow:>task create baz --definition "foo && bar"
Command failed org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: The 'task:foo' application could not be found.
The 'task:foo' application could not be found.
org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: The 'task:foo' application could not be found.
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.VndErrorResponseErrorHandler.handleError(VndErrorResponseErrorHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:782)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:418)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.TaskTemplate.create(TaskTemplate.java:156)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.shell.command.TaskCommands.create(TaskCommands.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.shell.core.SimpleExecutionStrategy.invoke(SimpleExecutionStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.shell.core.SimpleExecutionStrategy.execute(SimpleExecutionStrategy.java:59)
    at org.springframework.shell.core.AbstractShell.executeCommand(AbstractShell.java:134)
    at org.springframework.shell.core.JLineShell.promptLoop(JLineShell.java:533)
    at org.springframework.shell.core.JLineShell.run(JLineShell.java:179)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It seems that a Composed Task can only consist of basic Task Applications. Why can't I create a Composed Task that consists of other Composed Tasks? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. SCDF doesn't have support for running Composed Tasks within another Composed Task. Please feel free to open an enhancement request here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues. Thanks!

Comment: What I want to know is the rationale of the design. Can you please tell me more about it? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, the design challenge is right at the parser level. Currently, we have a dedicated Composed Task Parser that parses the composed task definition and parses the individual task definitions using the Task Parser. This is what I meant by the design here. But, of course we can change the design by considering your use case. I recommend filing an enhancement request here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues and possibly contribute as well. Thanks!

Comment: I've posted https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/4110. Thank you for the answer and suggestion.